# Save a video locally as iPhone app when downloaded from a server

Tags: iphone, caching

Can you download a video using MySQL database from server with WIFI or Internet connection, then save a video and stored locally on iPhone for time limit using cache.

**Or,** when a video is downloaded using MySQL database and after it plays, then close a video. Does this video disappear forever or do I have to download a same video again?

I'm using MySQL, PHP and HTML as well as CSS3, JS and jQuery to create an app using Cordova Framework. It is iPhone app.

Please advise?

Comment: How do you want to "download a video using MySQL"?

Comment: Using PHP. I'm talking about potentially saving a video on iPhone local storage using cache manifest after download and play a video. Its it feasible that a video can be stored on iphone local storage until time lapse using cache. Or, do I have to download again as it doesn't save on local storage as it is iphone app..

Comment: @Iriahgirl if you explicitly download a file, it'll stay there, don't rely on WebKit's caching mechanism, though.